# condition is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am checking condition here to select value in dropdown box. But the following line is not working it seems.

```
<option value="Chairman"'+ val["designation"]== "Chairmain" ? "selected" : "" +'>Chairman</option>
```

I think there is issue with `'` and `"`. i have tried many ways to fix it but it didn't help.

Following is my full code which I am using:

```
$.each(management_details,function(key,val){
    cnt++;
    htm += '<select name="management[]" class="repeat-select-management">\n\
        <option value="0">Select Management</option>\n\
        <option value="Chairman"'+ val["designation"]== "Chairmain" ? "selected" : "" +'>Chairman</option>\n\
        <option value="Vice Chairman">Vice Chairman</option>\n\
        <option value="Vice Chancellor">Vice Chancellor</option>\n\
        <option value="Secretary">Secretary</option>\n\
        <option value="Registrar">Registrar</option>\n\
        <option value="Dean">Dean</option>\n\
        <option value="Owner">Owner</option>\n\
        <option value="Other">Other</option>\n\
    </select>';
});
```

Can anyone suggest me how fix it?

Comment: Trying to figure out what this code is doing hurts. Stop generating HTML by smashing strings together and use DOM.

Comment: i am just checking if val["desgination"] has Chairmain then it will get selected in dropdown

Comment: `"'+ (val["designation"]== "Chairmain" ? "selected" : "") +'>` Use brackets to stop the ternary operator from being greedy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding paren around the ternary statement should do the trick.

Try replacing this line:

```
'<option value="Chairman"'+
    val["designation"]== "Chairmain" ? "selected" : "" +
    '>Chairman</option>\n\'
```

With:

```
'<option value="Chairman"'+
    (val["designation"]== "Chairmain" ? "selected" : "") +
    '>Chairman</option>\n\ '
```

JavaScript was probably getting confused about what does belong in the `else` part of the ternary statement, and what doesn't.

(I added the single quotes to remove the need to place the whole multiline string in my answer)